# Cannot find Trash folder in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, delete, trash

I have already asked here but nobody was able to respond or provide any answers.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506687/cannot-find-trash-folder-ubuntu-18-04

I am running a preinstalled version of Ubuntu 18.04 but cannot find Trash folder. The typical places don't have the folder.

The directory should most likely be here but it's not

```
 /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash  <---does not exist
```

Running a search via find as follows

```
sudo find / -type d -iname Trash
```

and

```
sudo find / -type f -iname Trash
```

I get in both cases some unrelated trash directory and in both cases:

```
find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

My question is :  where is my TRASH FOLDER ? And why do I receive the following output when I run the find command

```
find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

Also, note that I do have a trash bin on my desktop. But that's always empty. 
It tried to delete some distinct filename in my ~/Downloads folder to see where the file went missing ...

It neither appeared in the 'TRASH bin' on my Desktop, nor anywhere where I could use the command:

```
sudo find / -type d -iname deletedfile
```

or

```
sudo find / -type f -iname deletedfile
```

This should be weird for a newbie. Kindly advise what to do here..

Comment: Do you have a non-empty `XDG_DATA_HOME` variable in your environment (i.e. output of `echo $XDG_DATA_HOME` in a terminal)?

Comment: I get one empty line as output ?!

Comment: OK so that means that you *don't* - fair enough, it was just something to rule out

Comment: I have posted an answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613673/146438. Thanks.